# PHP Pretty URLs with htaccess without changing the URL

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I have searched many similiar questions but I couldn't find an answer. I have a php website that has users and I want to create user profile pages.

Now, it works like this:

```
https://example.com/profile?userid=user_id_here
```

But I want it work like this:

```
https://example.com/profile/user_id_here
```

When users click on the their profile url, which is:

`https://example.com/profile/user_id_here`

I want the page silently call this url:

```
https://example.com/profile?userid=user_id_here
```

So users will always see the friendly url without question mark and userid= part.

I don't want to redirect this page ( https://example.com/profile?userid=user_id_here ) to this page ( https://example.com/profile/user_id_here ) because users will not see this one ( https://example.com/profile?userid=user_id_here ).

I just want profile.php silently to call the spesific pretty url.

My current rewrite rules are below and I want the new rule to add the rules below:

```
RewriteEngine On

# match any URL with www and rewrite it to https without the www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# match urls that are non https (without the www)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#remove .php
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

I spent like more than 2 days for this but I couldn't find a solution. Any help with the explanation what the rule is doing is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try this
I haven't tested it but should work

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ /profile?userid=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Your rule also matches `/profile/index.php` which will result in an infinite loop error.

Comment: Hi @starkeen , so when does it match it and how do I avoid it? Is it a big problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine On

# match any URL with www and rewrite it to https without the www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# match urls that are non https (without the www)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#remove .php
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]

#rewrite /profile/userID to /profile?userid=userID
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^profile/(.+)$ /profile?userid=$1 [L,NC]
```

`RewriteConds` ensure that you don't rewrite your existing directories and files to `/profile?userid` .

Comment: I added the `RewriteCond`s and the `RewriteRule` to my `.htaccess`, as well as the `[L,NC]` flags. However, it rewrites the "pretty" URL to the "ugly" URL in the search bar instead of it silently calling the "ugly" URL.

Comment: Answer to my comment above: for me it helped to change `profile?userid=x` to `profile/?userid=x` (the pretty URL is `/profile/x/`, the ugly URL is `/profile?userid=x`